# Can't update mosquitto-clients from 1.4.15 to 1.6.9

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mosquitto, tls1.3, libmosquitto

To update mosquitto-clients, I have tried

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mosquitto-clients
```

However, this doesn't update the version for me.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
mosquitto-clients is already the newest version (1.4.15-2ubuntu0.18.04.3).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bridge-utils ubuntu-fan
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 73 not upgraded.
```

I want to use tls1.3 (using `mosquitto_pub --tls-version tlsv1.3`) and from the system with 1.4.15 I get  `Error: Problem setting TLS options.`
When using mosquitto_pub from Ubuntu wsl with mosquitto-clients 1.6.9, I can easily connect and send data.

Can someone help please. Both systems are linux.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the [documentation](https://mosquitto.org/blog/2013/01/mosquitto-debian-repository/) to configure the repo so you can see all the versions available.

Then if you need to install version `1.6.10` (I did not see `1.6.9`)

```
root@debian1:~# apt install mosquitto-clients=1.6.10-0mosquitto1~buster1 libmosquitto1=1.6.10-0mosquitto1~buster1
```

To search for all the versions available for a package.

```
root@debian1:~# apt-cache policy mosquitto-clients | less
```

But it depends on `libmosquitto1` library so please also check that.

```
root@debian1:~# apt-cache policy libmosquitto1 | less
```